# B2C- Customization of signing up page (custom policy)

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

**UPDATE**

**I used [split email verification and sign up](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/split-email-verification-and-signup) for my sign up process.
On the 4th page I added a button to allow changing the email address.**

**How to allow user to reset email validation (picture 1) when he clicks on the change email button, knowing that at this step of process, the input "email" and the button for sending code "email_ver_but_send" are not hidden but not exist when inspecting the page?**

Those are my pages for signing up  :

**1-Validation email**

[image: 1-Validate email]

**2- Validate code**

[image: 2- Validate code]

**3- Change email**

[image: 3- Change email]

**4- Create account**

[image: 4- Create account]

My questions are :

1- How to hide continue and cancel buttons in steps 1-2-3 and only display them in the 4th step of the process?

2- After checking the code (step 2), how to go directly to step 4?

Thanks for help

Comment: Why this negative vote? Is there something not clear in my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a metadata setting called `setting.showCancelButton` that can be added to the self asserted technical profile. This has the possible value of `true` for showing the button and `false` for not showing the button.

Here is an example

```
    <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-Page">
      <DisplayName>Self Asserted Page</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="setting.showCancelButton">false</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

More information about the metadata keys for self-asserted technical profiles can be found on the [Microsoft documentation website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile#metadata).

Comment: Won't this hide buttons during the whole process?

Comment: Yes it would do that. If this is all happening on one page the only option would be to use JavaScript to show or hide the button.